# How do I escape a PHP script to an external editor and return afterwards?

Tags: php, shell, command-line, user-input

Specifically I have a PHP command-line script that at a certain point requires input from the user. I would like to be able to execute an external editor (such as vi), and wait for the editor to finish execution before resuming the script.

My basic idea was to use a temporary file to do the editing in, and to retrieve the contents of the file afterwards. Something along the lines of:

```
$filename = '/tmp/script_' . time() . '.tmp';

get_user_input ($filename);

$input = file_get_contents ($filename);
unlink ($filename);
```

I suspect that this isn't possible from a PHP command-line script, however I'm hoping that there's some sort of shell scripting trick that can be employed to achieve the same effect.

Suggestions for how this can be achieved in other scripting languages are also more than welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can redirect the editor's output to the terminal:

```
system("vim > `tty`");
```

Comment: Can't believe this was so easy.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this and it works fine in windows, so you can probably replicate with vi or whatever app you want on Linux.

The key is that `exec()` hangs the php process while notepad (in this case) is running.

```
<?php

exec('notepad c:\test'); 
echo file_get_contents('c:\test');

?>

$ php -r test.php
```

Edit: As your attempt shows and bstark pointed out, my notepad test fires up a new window so all is fine, but any editor that runs in console mode fails because it has no terminal to attach to.

That being said, I tried on a Linux box with `exec('nano test'); echo file_get_contents('test');` and it doesn't fail as badly as vi, it just runs without displaying anything. I could type some stuff, press "ctrl-X, y" to close and save the file, and then the php script continued and displayed what I had written. Anyway.. I found the proper solution, so new answer coming in.

Answer (score 0):

```
system('vi');
```

http://www.php.net/system

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's at all possible to connect vi to the terminal php is running on, but the quick and easy solution is not to use a screen editor on the same terminal.

You can either use a line editor such as ed (you probably don't want that) or open a new window, like system("xterm -e vi") (replace xterm with the name of your terminal app).

Edited to add: In perl, system("vi") just works, because perl doesn't do the kind of fancy pipelining/buffering php does.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems your idea of writing a file lead us to try crazy things while there is an easy solution :)

```
<?php

$out = fopen('php://stdout', 'w+');
$in = fopen('php://stdin', 'r+');

fwrite($out, "foo?\n");
$var = fread($in, 1024);
echo strtoupper($var);
```

The fread() call will hang the php process until it receives something (1024 bytes or end of line I think), producing this :

```
$ php test.php
foo?
bar <= my input
BAR
```

Comment: Sure, you can do this, but it's not exactly what I was after. My point was that I wanted to the flexibility of an external editor like vi or similar.

Comment: Alright then sorry I thought you just came up with that idea as a hack to get user input, anyway it's settled I see.